# Update Creation time of browser at runtime using QTP

Tags: qtp

I want to update creation time of a browser at runtime using QTP.

I tried using setToProperty but it did not work.

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried, along with details or a screenshot of your chosen Browser object's identifiers in the OR.

Answer (score 2):

The `creation time` properties name is a bit misleading, it's not a time but a number of the `Browser`'s order of creation (the first one is `0` then `1` etc.).

This seems to work

```
 Browser("B").SetTOProperty "creationtime",  2
```

Comment: I agree with Moti, for my own necesities I had to try it and what he says works.